# How to wait for Rails service response before continuing controller action after_update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

On my website, users can upload documents (thanks to Cloudinary gem) thanks to simple_form_for :

`<%= f.cl_image_upload(:ids, allowed_formats: %w(jpg jpeg png)) %>`

and these documents are sent to Stripe thanks to their API.
So in my user model, I put :

`after_update send_documents_to_stripe, if: :documents_are_upload?`

(It just checks if the user has uploaded his documents and if so, the function to send the documents to Stripe is called)

Except that `after_update` waits for the documents to be entered in the database but it does not wait for the documents to be available on Cloudinary.

So when I try to send the documents to Stripe, I get this error:

[Error form rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjYHl.jpg)

Does anyone know how technically I can wait to make sure that Cloudinary has received the images from the user before sending the documents to Stripe?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the Cloudinary stuff, but you can also do this totally client-side, uploading directly to Stripe: https://jsfiddle.net/thorstripe/bdm3j2rn/

```
console.log("Code because I linked a JSFiddle...");
```

Comment: Hello floatingLomas! 
Thank you very much for your help

It works very well! I have just one more question, this document I would like to associate to a connected account but when I add this :

```data.append('stripe_account', stripe_account_id);```

I get an error, ```invalid params```. Do you know how I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact complete error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try using `after_save` instead of `after_update`.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work :/